# Busqueda en mysql de 4 tablas

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas amigos espero que puedan ayudarme, el problema es el siguiente..
Tengo **4 tablas** en ***MYSQL*** , deseo buscar en cada una de ellas

**Campo de tabla1:**

```
id,numero
```

**Campo de tabla2:**

```
nombre, apellido
```

**Campo de tabla3:**

```
id,condicion,identificador
```

**Campo de tabla4:**

```
id,razonsocial
```

Mi intencion es mostrar el **nombre,apellido** de la ***tabla2***,,  **razonsocial** de la ***tabla4***,,  y **id,numero** de la ***tabla1***
esta es mi consulta

```
  <?php
     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT 
      tabla1.id, 
      tabla1.numero, 
      tabla2.nombre, 
      tabla2.apellido, 
      tabla4.razonsocial 
      FROM tabla1, tabla2, tabla3, tabla4 
      WHERE 
      tabla1.numero=tabla3.id 
      AND (tabla3.condicion=1 AND tabla3.identificador=tabla4.id) 
      OR (tabla3.condicion=2 AND tabla3.identificador=tabla2.id)";

      $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
          $id=$row["id"];
            $numero=$row["numero"]; 
            $nombre=$row['nombre'];
            $apellido=$row['apellido'];
            $razonsocial=$row['razonsocial'];
       }
      echo $nombre." ".$apellido;
  ?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme , muchas gracias!!

Les dejo un EJEMPLO mas claro:

**TABLA1**= factura, **TABLA2**= Persona, **TABLA3**= Cliente, **TABLA4**= Empresa

Supongamos que necesito buscar el nombre del **Cliente PERTENECIENTE A DICHA FACTURA** sabiendo que ese cliente puede ser una **PERSONA O UNA EMPRESA**

En tal caso tengo el identificador... si **identificador** = 1 debo buscar en la tabla de ***EMPRESAS (tabla4)*** de lo contrario si **identificador** = 2 debo buscar en la tabla de ***PERSONAS (tabla2)***

Comment: No tienes establecidas las relaciones correctamente entre las tablas.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar **cómo**  se relacionan las tablas entre sí? Por lo que dices en la edición: `tabla1` se relaciona con `tabla4` cuando el `id` de `tabla1` es igual 1;  `tabla1` se relaciona con `tabla2` cuando el `id` de `tabla1` es igual 2. **¿Hay más relaciones de ese tipo a tomar en cuenta? ... Y otra pregunta: ¿en caso de necesidad de cambiar el diseño de las tablas, tienes libertad para hacerlo o debes ceñirte obligatoriamente al diseño actual?

Comment: si tienes alguna otra manera de ver las tablas seria perfecto...
**primera relacion:**
tabla1.numero = tabla3.id

**segunda relacion: siempre y cuando condicion sea 1**
(tabla3.condicion = 1 AND tabla3.identificador=tabla4.id), el debe mostrar los campos 
$nombre=$row['nombre'];
$apellido=$row['apellido'];
 que estan en wl **WHILE**

**tercera relacion siempre y cuando condicion sea = 2 :**
(tabla3.condicion = 2 AND tabla3.identificador = tabla2.id)

Comment: si en la tabla3.condicion=1 entonces debe buscar en la tabla3.identificador = tabla4.id

Comment: si en la tabla3.condicion=2 entonces debe buscar tabla3.identificador = tabla2.id

Comment: Aún leyéndolo en los comentarios hay que hacer tremendo esfuerzo para entender lo que quieres expresar. ¿Podrías por favor editar la pregunta y explicar con la mayor claridad posible cuáles son las diferentes relaciones/condiciones de la tablas, como si tuvieras que explicárselas a un bebé de 3 años y que éste las entienda? Intuyo que plantear la pregunta es complicado porque has emprendido un diseño y relación de tablas que no son quizá los más correctos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema para unir las tablas con las foreing keys , por consiguiente lo recomendable que añadas a la tabla pivote que es la Tabla 3 por lo que puedo ver , añadir un datos_id que sería la foreing key a la Tabla 2.

```
Tabla 1         Tabla 3                 
id  numero      id  condicion   identificador   datos_id        
1   65           1    1           1              2              
2   45           2    2           2              1                              

        Tabla 2                 Tabla 4 
        id  nombre  apellido    id  razonsocial
        1   a        g           1  casado
        2   b        h           2  soltero
```

La consulta que creo que puede funcionar es :

```
SELECT tabla2.nombre , tabla2.apellido , tabla4.razonsocial , tabla1.id , tabla1.numero
FROM tabla1 , tabla2 , tabla3 , tabla4
WHERE (tabla1.id = tabla3.identificador) AND (tabla3.condicion = tabla4.id) 
  AND (tabla3.datos_id = tabla2.id)
```

Comment: entiendo lo que me quieres decir pero dependo del **tabla3.identificador** a que si este **identificador=1 debo buscar en la tabla4** y si **identificador=2 debo buscar en la tabla2**

Comment: te pongo otro ejemplo: **TABLA1= factura**, **TABLA2= Persona**, **TABLA3= Cliente**, **TABLA4= Empresa**

Supongamos que necesito buscar el nombre del Cliente **PERTENECIENTE A DICHA FACTURA** sabiendo que ese cliente puede ser una **PERSONA O UN EMPRESA**

Comment: En tal caso tengo el identificador...

si **identificador** = 1 debo buscar en la tabla de **EMPRESAS (tabla4)** de lo contrario si **identificador** = 2 debo buscar en la tabla de **PERSONAS (tabla2)**

Comment: @David en vez de explicar eso aquí en comentario, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/101225/edit)  explicando esos detalles importantes, de ese modo podrás obtener una respuesta que resuelva tu problema. No estamos en tu mente para intuir ese tipo de situaciones que expresas en los dos comentarios anteriores. Si hay más detalles de ese tipo debes indicarlos claramente en la pregunta.

Comment: gracias @A. Cedano, espero puedas seguirme ayudando!!